# YouTube API Not Muting in Safari (not iOS)

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have initialized my player with the code below. It mutes fine in Chrome, FireFox, and IE, but not Safari. Any thoughts amigos?

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('iframe-wrapper', {
        height: videoHeight,
        width: videoWidth,
        videoId: id,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        },
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'controls': 0,
            'autohide': 1,
            'wmode': 'opaque',
            'showinfo': 0,
            'loop': 1,
            'mute': 1
        }
    });
}
  function onPlayerReady() {
    player.mute();
    player.playVideo();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the onPlayerReady event wasn't firing. Apparently this is somewhat of a known issue and isn't terribly well documented in the YouTube API. [Here's a link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20504912/2440579).

Answer (score 0):

Just add some code in your `onPlayerReady()`:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target.mute();
}
```

or you can create a separate function for mute:

```
function onMute() {
player.mute();
}

function onUnMute() {
player.unMute();
}
```

Follow the guide code in [youtube api document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) and [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/zohf/Luoyon0x/).