# YouTube iframe API changeState isn't being called

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am trying to use the [YouTube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to fire an event after a video is finishing playing. The iframe containing the YouTube video is loaded with the document and has the `enablejsapi=1` parameter in the URL like so:

```
<iframe id="myytplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/8mmd_eHYmMY?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have successfully implemented the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function but I cannot add an event listener to the YouTube object once it is ready. **The player state alert does not show when playing/pausing the video.** Here is my javascript code:

```
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
    // check player ended
}
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    alert("ready");
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", onytplayerStateChange);
}
```

I also had to load the following resource in order to get the "ready" alert to show up.

```
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have created a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wh7Xk/4/).

Comment: see here, its probably the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078094/youtube-iframe-player-api-onstatechange-not-firing

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an event listener just to the DOM element (as you could do in the older javascript API); with the iframe API you have to create a YT.player object based on the DOM element first, and then add the event listener there. Something like this:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    ytplayer = YT.Player("myytplayer", {
    events: {
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
}
```

Also, be a bit careful loading the player_api via a script tag ... there's no guarantee that your onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function will be defined when that's fully loaded. Better to do something like this, before defining your ready function:

```
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```