# YouTube iFrame API 'onStateChange' not firing in Firefox

Tags: firefox, youtube, youtube-api

As of today, I'm having some difficulty getting the YouTube iFrame API `onStateChange` to fire in Firefox.

This appears to be a new problem - projects using the same code with the same API that were working fully last week are now not firing their `onStateChange` events. This issue only seems to affect Firefox - Chrome and Internet Explorer are working fully.

Is this a known bug, and is there a workaround available if it is?

(There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078094/youtube-iframe-player-api-onstatechange-not-firing), but it appears to be for a temporary bug on YouTube's side that has now been fixed. The solution posted there also doesn't seem to fix this issue.)

As an example, here's a fiddle using the [basic example from Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). The player should stop after six seconds, but doesn't:

http://jsfiddle.net/wf4NW/

```
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have the same issue from today, the state is not changed anymore on firefox.

Comment: This issue is reported in https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6531

Issue is recognized by dev team and a quick fix is on the way.

Comment: link to gdata issue https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6531

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the YouTube flash player. When flash is used (which seems to be the default) the API does not work.

However, when HTML5 mode is requested, the stateChange event does fire.

```
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      playerVars: {
        html5: 1
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

[Here is the OP's jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf4NW/1/), but modified to use the HTML5 player. With the HTML5 player, the video **does** pause after 6 seconds like it should.

Comment: I had success with this workaround on Firefox.  It does not work when you try to add the listeners on an already-instantiated iframe in the DOM.