# Iframe api state change does not trigger with mdl js

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

The iframe api onStateChange does not get triggered when mdl js is present.

[See codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzJRVJ) . This will not console log state changes , deleting

```
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
```

will console log the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078094/youtube-iframe-player-api-onstatechange-not-firing), there was a temporary issue with the iFrame Player API and as a temporary fix, you just need to add the event listener within the `onReady` event:

```
function onReady() {
    player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
        console.log('State is:', e.data);
    });
}
```

Make sure to remove the `onStateChange` event from the YT.PLAYER constructor [(see the jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffposnick/yhWsG/3/).