# Youtube API Does Not Work for <iFrame>

Tags: api, iframe, youtube

After onPlayerReady and onPlayerStateChage is not triggered, did I do something wrong with the code?

I am trying not to use `<div id="player></div>`

Anyone having the same problem as me?

Please let me know if you have any question in regards to my question.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag.-->
    <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player1', {
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if(event.data === 0) {            
            alert('done');
        }

        /*if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }*/
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code loads the video player just fine. Is the problem that you are not getting autoplay?
One possible reason for that beahviour:

[no autoplay in iframe HTML5 player on mobile (Android Chrome and Firefox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959454/no-autoplay-in-iframe-html5-player-on-mobile-android-chrome-and-firefox)

Additionally, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230279/youtube-iframe-api-onready-and-onstatechanged-events-not-firing-in-ie9?rq=1) advises you to have flash enabled and updated.